# Setting global routes for single controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have set `/admin` prefix for all routes in a single bundle, but I also want to set some global prefix for a single controller inside of this bundle. So if I have `FooController` created, I could write:

```
@Route("/foomethod", name="/foomethod")
```

instead of:

```
@Route("/FooController/foomethod", name="/FooControler/foomethod")
```

Is there a way to do this, and is this considered a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's in fact a good practice to solve things DRY ( dont repeat yourself ).

You can have the @Route annotation on your controller class specifying the desired prefix like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/foocontroller")
 */
class FooController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/bar")
     */
     public function barAction()
     {
        // ... 
     }

    /**
     * @Route("/blub")
     */
     public function blubAction()
     {
        // ... 
     }
```

Resulting in **/foocontroller/bar** for your barAction() and **/foocontroller/blub** for blubAction().